# props.history.push is not working properly and redirecting to same route

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom, react-props

So, I am making a basic React App, With 3 Components, CreateRoom and SetUsername and Window. Initially i navigate to the createRoom component with a simple `<Link to="/createRoom" >create a room</Link>`, Then in the createRoom component, after the user has set the Room name, i navigate to the SetUsername component through `props.history.push({pathname})` and pass in the Room_name through `props.history.push()`, then once i am in the SetUsername Component, i wait for the user to set the username, and pass that username to the window object again through props.history.push() and use the room_name acquired through `props.history.location.state.room_name` to navigate through URL params. But when i press submit in the createRoom component, react renders the home component set at route `"/"` but the URL shown is `"/set-user-name"` which is the URL of SetUsername Component. So the behaviour i want to achieve is that after passing room_name through props, i use that room_name in another component to navigate to the window component through SetUsername through URL params , but along that also pass in the username through props to the window component.

***Below is the console.log(props) when i press submit in the createRoom component.***

```
{history: {…}, location: {…}, match: {…}, staticContext: undefined}
history:
action: "PUSH"
block: ƒ block(prompt)
createHref: ƒ createHref(location)
go: ƒ go(n)
goBack: ƒ goBack()
goForward: ƒ goForward()
length: 7
listen: ƒ listen(listener)
location: {pathname: "/set-user-name", state: {…}, search: "", hash: "", key: "8gq7s3"}
push: ƒ push(path, state)
replace: ƒ replace(path, state)
__proto__: Object
location:
hash: ""
key: "o7exh2"
pathname: "/create-room"
search: ""
state: undefined
__proto__: Object
match:
isExact: true
params: {}
path: "/create-room"
url: "/create-room"
__proto__: Object
staticContext: undefined
__proto__: Object
```

**App.js**

```
    const App = () => {
      return (
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/create-room" component={CreateRoom} />
            <Route path="/" component={Nav} />
            <Route path="set-user-name" component={SetUsername} />
 <Route path="/:room" component={Window} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      );
    };
    
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**createRoom.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
const CreateRoom = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({});
  return (
    <div className="center-wrapper">
      <input
        className="room-input"
        placeholder="Room Name"
        onChange={(event) => {
          setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
        }}
        name="room"
      />
      <div
        className="btn"
        onClick={() => {
          props.history.push({
            pathname: `/set-user-name`,
            state: { room_name: state.room },
          });
        }}
      >
        Create Room
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(CreateRoom);
```

**SetUsername.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import InputForm from "./InputForm.js";

var room_name = "DEFAULT_USERNAME";

const SetUsername = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    room_name = props.history.location.state.room_name;
  }, []);
  const [username, SetUsername] = React.useState({});
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    SetUsername({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    props.history.push({
      pathname: `/${room_name}`,
      state: { username: username.username },
    });
  };
  return (

    <InputForm
      inp_placeholder={"Enter a display name"}
      pass_placeholder={undefined}
      inp_className={"for-input"}
      pass_className={undefined}
      onChange={handleChange}
      onClick={handleSubmit}
      inputName={"username"}
      passName={undefined}
      inputRequired={true}
      passRequired={false}
      buttonText={"submit"}
    />
  );
};

export default withRouter(SetUsername);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your component `SetUsername.js` you have the same name from the component `const SetUsername = (props) =>` as state function in `[username, SetUsername] = React.useState({})`. I suggest changing to `setUsername`.

Other problem that I can see is about having a variable `var room_name = "DEFAULT_USERNAME";`. This is not a good pattern and will bring problem to your application.

I have this sandbox with a good example about handling with `react-router` with Hooks. https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-example-using-react-router-2yovb?file=/src/App.js